# a representation of $f''$ only using terms of $f$ and constants.

Tags: real-analysis

Using Taylor formulare How can I prove the following result? 
$
f''\left( x \right) \approx Af\left( x \right) + Bf\left( {x + h} \right) + Cf\left( {x + 2h} \right) + Df\left( {x + 3h} \right)\,\,h > 0
$

Obviously I have to consider the taylor expansion and "playing" with the terms, but that's my problem . Sorry for asking this stupid things

Comment: For reference, what you are looking at is "finite difference approximations" for the second derivative. In the numerical analysis literature finding optimal coefficients $A,B,C,D$ to minimise the error often uses the method of "underdetermined coefficients". One may wish to consult a textbook on "finite difference methods" for more information. For example, some discussion is given in Chapter 1 of Randall LeVeque's _Finite Different Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for $1 \le i \le 3$
\[ f(x+ih) = f(x) + ihf'(x) + \frac 12 {i^2}{h^2}f''(x) + \frac 16{i^3}{h^3}f'''(x) + O(h^4)
\]
So we have for your right hand side
\begin{align*}
   f(x)\bigl(A + B + C + D)\\
{} + f'(x)\bigl(B + 2C + 3D\bigr)h\\
{} + f''(x)\frac 12\bigl(B + 4C + 9D\bigr)h^2\\
{} + f'''(x)\frac 16 \bigl(B + 8C + 27D)h^3\\
{} + O(h^4)
\end{align*}
So we want to have
\begin{align*}
  A + B + C + D &= 0\\
      B + 2C + 3D &= 0\\
      B + 4C + 9D &= 0
\end{align*}
Wlog we can let $A = 1$. Then our System gives 
\begin{align*}
      B + C + D   &= -1\\
          C + 2D &= 1\\
         3C + 8D &= 1
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
      B + C + D   &= -1\\
          C + 2D &= 1\\
              2D &= -2
\end{align*}
so $D = -1$, $C = 3$, $B = -3$. Then $B + 8C + 27D = -3+24-27 = -6$. That gives
\[ 
  f'''(x) = \frac{-f(x) + 3f(x+h) - 3f(x+2h) + f(x+3h)}{h^3} + O(h).
\]

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but why you can assume Wlog that A=1? The original problem it's aproximate $f''$ with an order of $O(h^2)$ but does not matter, if I understand your proof, I'll be able to do in the other case

Comment: @Daniel It's not worded in the best way.  It's not really WLOG, but martini is choosing $A=1$ for concreteness, with the awareness that all other solutions will be given by rescaling everything by a constant.  Notice in the end that $A = -1/h^3$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Write
\begin{align}
f(x+h) & = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(x) + \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(\zeta_1) \\\
f(x+2h) & = f(x) + 2hf'(x) + \frac{(2h)^2}2 f''(x) + \frac{(2h)^3}{6}f'''(\zeta_2) \\\
f(x+3h) & = f(x) + 3hf'(x) + \frac{(3h)^2}2 f''(x) + \frac{(3h)^3}{6}f'''(\zeta_3). \\\
\end{align}
Then after you work out the equations, you get
$$
\begin{align}
A f(x) + B f(x+h) & + C f(x+2h) + D f(x+3h) \\\
& = \\\
(A+B+C+D)f(x) + (B+2C + 3D)hf'(x) &+ \left( \frac B2 + 2C + \frac 92D \right)h^2 f''(x) + \text{error term}
\end{align}
$$
where the error term contains the third derivatives. So just solve for
$$
\begin{align}
A+B+C+D = 0 \\\
B+2C + 3D = 0 \\\
B +2C + 9D/2 = 1/h^2 \\\
\end{align}
$$
and you will find four functions of $h$ ($A(h)$, $B(h)$, $C(h)$ and $D(h)$) such that your approximation is as good as the upper bound you can put on the third derivative error term.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $$f'(x)h\approx f(x+h)-f(x),$$ 
we get
$$\begin{align}f''(x)h^2&\approx f'(x+h)h-f'(x)h \\ &\approx f(x+2h)-f(x+h)-(f(x+h)-f(x))\\ &= f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)\end{align}$$
Repeat: 
$$\begin{align}f'''(x)h^3&\approx f''(x+h)h-f''(x)h \\&\approx (f(x+3h)-2f(x+2h)+f(x+h))-(f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x))\\ &= f(x+3h)-3f(x+2h)+3f(x+h)-f(x)\end{align}$$
You can go on as long as you like... The coefficients are binomial with alternating signs.

Perhaps this approach does not quality as *using the Taylor expansion*, but it seems less painful.